# Unity3D Physics2D disable deformation

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

I am trying to use Physics2D in Unity and simply place blocks on top of each other.
My project setup:

I have a sprite as floor with a Box2D collider. I have a prefab which is also a sprite with 1.5 x 0.5 x 1 scale and also a box collider and a rigidbody2D.

What I do is to place blocks on top of each other on the same x axis:
Here is my code:

```
public GameObject testInstance; //Prefab Box
public float m_fSpawnY = -3.1f; //Start Y for first box
public float m_fSpawnYAdd = 0.5f; //for next box


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N))
    {
        Instantiate(testInstance, new Vector3(0, m_fSpawnY , 0), Quaternion.identity);
        m_fSpawnY += m_fSpawnYAdd ;
    }
}
```

My problem now is that the more boxes I add, the more the objects below get "squeezed", which might be correct for real physics but for my use-case I would like to disable the deformation completely because the build tower gets instable the more I place on top.

Is it somehow possible to deactivate deformation? I tried to use Physics Material 2D but it only gives friction and bouncyness but I have set boucyness to 0 and it has no effect.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Hi, Where does your object spawn? above all of the other object or "inside"? because from my test i have this "squeeze" effect when the spawn position is colliding with another box, then the box move to get out of the collision which look like the boxes are squeezed. is that what you have?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your fast answer. I spawn blocks little above the prev block, it starts falling through gravity and blocks are stacked that way. The more blocks I have the more the tower get squeezed because of the preasure of the other blocks on top => it looks like a rubber tower and after spawning several blocks on top it gets totally instable and the tower falls apart. I also tried to increase the density but then it also increases the mass (only usable with automass) an I have the same effect. I would like to have something like wooden blocks that wont get squeezed.

Comment: Do you have an image of the result to be sure we are talking about the same "squeeze"?

Comment: I put the assest folder of my project into google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15eNoCJQptvkoE2hBfRoPexPKm-B9qx_c?usp=sharing
If you press N in Play-Mode a block will be spawned, if you do that several times, you will see its bouncyness

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this problem by changing some value in your project settings, basically the "velocity iterations" and the "position iterations". This will consume more resources but will generate a more accurate move and therefore less "bouncing". You should play around with those value to find what suit the best for your project.

I think this is a side effect of the "sample rate" at which the physics is calculated, leading to small overlap of the object and then getting rejected creating this bouncy effect. the more your "sample rate" is high the more the collision detection is accurate but the more ressources are used.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. So there is no way to prevent objects to be deformed? I want to build a tower of boxes and it should work on mobile also. Its kind of like putting wooden blocks on top of each other in reality. If there is no other disturbing force like wind etc. I could stack hundreds of blocks without having an effect on stability (if I place the block perfectly in center) so the tower should only be affected by the point of mass of each block and not on the preasure of all blocks and its resulting instability...Right now, I dont know how to achive that

Comment: if the block doesn't have to fall on the other but just be creating on top of them you can move them manually thus you won't have the "bouncy" problem and then the physics can do the job for the rest.

Comment: thats what I was trying but the more i place on top the more pressure the blocks below get and the tower gets instable again... :( its not only the bouncyness its the gravity itself because gravity is always applied of course but the collider prevents falling but the more objects the more gravity affects the tower and it falls. I was thinking of deactivating gravity and then it works but then the tower wont fall if the block ist not placed in the middle of course...

Comment: you can see that effect in my project with follwowing setup: - ground sprit to scale y 1 and position to 0/0/0 - Main Camera values of attached component to Spawn Y 0.75  and Spawn Y Add 0.5 - When you hit play and start the game and continue to place objects through "N" you will see that the entire tower gets squeezed more and more and some time it falls apart